# Why sometimes the sequence keys is working and sometimes not responding?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When running the game in the editor when I press the keys sequence N,O,T,E,S it's opening a small window.  then when I type inside the window some text and also type /exit or /close it will close the window.

but then when I try to type the sequence of keys N,O,T,E,S again it's not opening the window again only after sometimes I press the keys sequence.

when typing the notes sequence first time it's working also in lower case.  and if I make the sequence NOTES and then not clicking on the window to get its focus and then type NOTES again it will toggle and open/close the window without a problem.

the problem I described happens after I click the window to get its focus and after typing some text inside then closing it with the command /close or /exist then when typing notes again it's not working immediately.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GameNotes : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool showNotes = false;
    private string notesContent = "";
    private static string filePath = "GameNotes.txt";
    private int keySequenceIndex = 0;
    private KeyCode[] keySequence = new KeyCode[] { KeyCode.N, KeyCode.O, KeyCode.T, KeyCode.E, KeyCode.S };

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(keySequence[keySequenceIndex]))
        {
            keySequenceIndex++;
            if (keySequenceIndex >= keySequence.Length)
            {
                showNotes = !showNotes;
                keySequenceIndex = 0;
                if (showNotes) LoadNotes();
            }
        }
        else if (Input.anyKeyDown)
        {
            keySequenceIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (showNotes)
        {
            GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 150, Screen.height / 2 - 100, 300, 200));
            GUI.Box(new Rect(0, 0, 300, 200), "Notes");
            string prevContent = notesContent;
            notesContent = GUI.TextArea(new Rect(10, 20, 280, 170), notesContent);
            GUI.EndGroup();

            // Detect special commands
            ProcessCommands();

            // Save notes if there's any change and no command was detected
            if (prevContent != notesContent && showNotes)
            {
                SaveNotes();
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProcessCommands()
    {
        if (notesContent.Contains("/close") || notesContent.Contains("/exit"))
        {
            showNotes = false;
            // Remove the command text from the notes
            notesContent = notesContent.Replace("/close", "").Replace("/exit", "").Trim();
            SaveNotes();
        }
    }

    private void SaveNotes()
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, notesContent);
    }

    private void LoadNotes()
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            notesContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I imagine happens: While you enter your notes content you eventually type a "random" amounts of  `n`, `o`, `t`, `e` and `s`.

=> When the window is closed, you think you are at the beginning of the sequence but you might not always be.

Thus, when you type the first letter `n` (again) when (for you) starting the sequence instead it might already expect another key and resets and ignores the rest of your input as well missing the entire next sequence.

---

I think there are a couple of points towards solving this

- In `ProcessCommands` along with

  ```
  showNotes = false;
  ```

  also reset

  ```
  keySequenceIndex = 0;
  ```

  in order to be sure to always check for a fresh sequence when the window is not opened
- In `Update` within the

  ```
  else if (Input.anyKeyDown)
  ```

  instead of only resetting

  ```
  keySequenceIndex = 0;
  ```

  rather check if this is maybe the beginning of the sequence - and start over directly. Otherwise as said in case you are already in the middle of the sequence and start with `n` again it will miss it and thereby miss the entire next sequence.

  ```
  else if(Input.GetKeyDown(keySequence[0]))
  {
      keySequenceIndex  = 1;
  }
  else if (Input.anyKeyDown)
  {
      keySequenceIndex  = 0;
  }
  ```
- I would also use hard values and instead of

  ```
  showNotes = !showNotes;
  ```

  rather use a clear

  ```
  showNotes = true;
  ```

  otherwise typing `notes` within your notes window might unexpectedly close it.
- And finally within `Update` simply ignore the entire input as long as the notes window is opened!

  ```
  void Update()
  {
      if (showNotes) return;

      ...
  }
  ```

  in order to not handle any content you type in the notes as input in the first place

---

Is there btw a reason why using IMGUI (`OnGUI`) which is quite legacy instead of good (and also) old [uGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/index.html) or the newest [UI Toolkit](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIElements.html)?

See also [Comparison of UI systems in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UI-system-compare.html)